# Help writing emacs lisp for emacs etags search

Tags: emacs, lisp, elisp

I'm looking for some help developing what I think should be an easy program.

I want something similar to Emacs tags-search command, but I want to collect all search results into a buffer. (I want to see all results of M-,)

I'm thinking this python style pseudo code should work, but I have no idea how to do this in emacs lisp? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
def myTagsGrep(searchValue):
    for aFile in the tag list:
        result = grep aFile seachValue
        if len(result) > 0:
            print aFile  # to the buffer
            print result # to the buffer
```

I would like to be able to browse through the buffer with the same features tags-apropos does.

Note that a similar question has been asked before:
[Is there a way to get emacs tag-search command to output all results to a buffer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4262887/is-there-a-way-to-get-emacs-tag-search-command-to-output-all-results-to-a-buffer/4393271#4393271)

Comment: Just as an aside, look at the lisp loop macro (some examples here http://www.ai.sri.com/pkarp/loop.html ) I think you'll like it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I'm such a fan of [`igrep`](http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/igrep.el), I'd use it as the building block.  From there it's two simple routines and you're done.  With that library and these two functions, all you have to do is:

```
M-x igrep-tags ^SomeRegexp.*Here RET
```

Here's the code:

```
(require 'igrep)
(defun igrep-tags (regex)
  (interactive "sTAGS Regexp: ")
  (igrep igrep-program regex (tags-file-names)))

(defun tags-file-names ()
  (save-excursion
    (visit-tags-table-buffer)
    (mapcar (lambda (f) (file-truename f))
            (tags-table-files))))
```

And, because the list of files can get really long, and you likely don't care what that list is, you can add these two pieces of code which will make the filenames invisible after the grep has finished:

```
(add-hook 'compilation-finish-functions 'igrep-tags-hide-filenames)

(defun igrep-tags-hide-filenames (buffer stat)
  "hide the filenames b/c they can get long"
  (save-excursion
    (set-buffer buffer)
    (save-match-data 
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (if (search-forward (combine-and-quote-strings (tags-file-names))
                          nil
                          (save-excursion (forward-line 10) (point)))
          (let ((display-string "..<files from TAGS>.."))
            (put-text-property (match-beginning 0) (match-end 0) 'invisible t)
            (put-text-property (match-beginning 0) (match-end 0) 'display display-string))))))
```

To avoid the really long command line, you can use the following code (which creates a temporary file containing all the names of files from TAGS file and uses that instead):

```
(defun igrep-tags (regex)
  (interactive "sTAGS Regexp: ")
  (let ((igrep-find t)
        (igrep-use-file-as-containing-files t))
    (igrep igrep-program regex nil)))

(defvar igrep-use-file-as-containing-files nil)

(defadvice igrep-format-find-command (around igrep-format-find-command-use-filename-instead activate)
  "use the second argument as a file containing filenames"
  (if igrep-use-file-as-containing-files
      (progn (with-temp-file
                 (setq igrep-use-file-as-containing-files (make-temp-file "tags-files"))
               (insert (combine-and-quote-strings (tags-file-names))))
             (setq ad-return-value (format "cat %s | xargs -e %s"
                                           igrep-use-file-as-containing-files
                                           (ad-get-arg 0))))
    ad-do-it))
```

And, for those using Emacs 22 or earlier, you'll need the routine that's shipped with Emacs 23 (from [subr.el](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/lisp/subr.el))

```
(defun combine-and-quote-strings (strings &optional separator)
  "Concatenate the STRINGS, adding the SEPARATOR (default \" \").
This tries to quote the strings to avoid ambiguity such that
  (split-string-and-unquote (combine-and-quote-strings strs)) == strs
Only some SEPARATORs will work properly."
  (let* ((sep (or separator " "))
         (re (concat "[\\\"]" "\\|" (regexp-quote sep))))
    (mapconcat
     (lambda (str)
       (if (string-match re str)
           (concat "\"" (replace-regexp-in-string "[\\\"]" "\\\\\\&" str) "\"")
         str))
     strings sep)))
```

Comment: I like this solution but for some of my TAGS the number of files is too long to handle. Any way of doing this by iterating over each file in the TAGS?

Comment: @user535707 I added a solution which addresses your issue.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but I cannot use combine-and-quote-strings on emacs22. Is there another function I can write to replace it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code I use to create a tag system for my personal notes.  It uses bookmarks and treats each word in a bookmark as a single tag.  Its not quite what you're looking for but it might get you started.

The first couple of functions are probably already implemented in emacs, but I wrote my own for reasons that I no longer recall.

```
;; FILTER keeps only elements of li for which pred returns true
(defun filter (pred li)
  (let (acc)
    (dolist (elem li)
      (if (funcall pred elem)
    (setq acc (cons elem acc))))
  (reverse acc)))


(defun string-match-all-p (str li)
   (if li
      (if (string-match-p (car li) str)
    (string-match-all-p str (cdr li))
   nil)
   t))

;;bookmarks as tags

(defun lookup-bookmark-tags (tagstring)
  (interactive "s")
   (let ((taglist (split-string tagstring " ")))
      (let ((bookmark-alist (filter 
           (lambda (elem)
             (string-match-all-p (car elem) taglist))
           bookmark-alist)))
    (call-interactively 'list-bookmarks))))
```

I then bind the 'tagging' behavior to a key (F11) and the 'lookup' behavior to another (F12).

```
(global-set-key [f11] 'bookmark-set)
(global-set-key [f12] 'lookup-bookmark-tags))
```

Hope that is useful to you.

Comment: Good Eye Victor, I think I've only posted once or twice.  I'll be sure to check it out.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you want:

http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Emacs_Tags_Enhancements#icicle-tags-search

This is the doc string for `icicle-tags-search`:

```
    Search all source files listed in tags tables for matches for REGEXP.
    You are prompted for the REGEXP to match.  Enter REGEXP with `RET'.
    You do not need `M-,' - you see all matches as search hits to visit.

    All tags in a tags file are used, including duplicate tags from the
    same or different source files.

    By default, all tags files are used, but if you provide a prefix
    argument then only the current tag table is used.

    If your TAGS file references source files that no longer exist, those
    files are listed.  In that case, you might want to update your TAGS
    file.


    You can alternatively choose to search, not the search contexts as
    defined by the context regexp you provide, but the non-contexts, that
    is, the text in the files that does not match the regexp.  To do this,
    use `C-M-~' during completion.  (This is a toggle, and it affects only
    future search commands, not the current one.)
```

See also this page for more explanation about **Icicles** search:

http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Search_Commands%2c_Overview

Comment: This works decent enough but there really isn't enoug information to make a good choise. The igrep solution posted by Trey provides all the source code on the line returned by grep.  I would love for icicles to encorperate something like this and even add the -A and -B option to grep.

Comment: @flanigan: Not sure what you mean. What `icicle-tags-search` does is this: Visit your TAGS files to get the list of all files that have defined tags, then search all of those files. The search is Icicles search, which means that you provide a regexp that defines the search contexts. If you want each line to be a context as in `grep`, then use `.*` as the context-defining regexp. You then type text (e.g. a substring or a regexp) in the minibuffer to filter the set of contexts (from all of the files).  You can use `S-SPC` to add more filtering patterns, to narrow the contexts progressively.

Comment: If you are not familiar with Icicles search then I suggest you try a simple search first: a single file, for instance. Start [*here*](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Search_Commands%2c_Overview).  My guess is that you are confused about the context regexp, thinking perhaps that it is used to search the files. For a line-by-line search a la `grep`, the context regexp should just be `.*`. The searching is via the dynamic search patterns that you type in the minibuffer.